# Spring Boot WebClient stops sending requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am running a Spring Boot app that uses WebClient for both non-blocking and blocking HTTP requests. After the app has run for some time, all outgoing HTTP requests seem to get stuck.

WebClient is used to send requests to multiple hosts, but as an example, here is how it is initialized and used to send requests to Telegram:

WebClientConfig:

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactorClientHttpConnector httpClient() {
        HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.builder("connectionProvider").build())
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectTimeout)
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(responseTimeout));
        return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
    }
```

The same ReactorClientHttpConnector is used for all WebClients.

TelegramClient:

```java
    @Autowired
    ReactorClientHttpConnector httpClient;

    WebClient webClient;

    RateLimiter rateLimiter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(httpClient)
                .baseUrl(telegramUrl)
                .build();

        rateLimiter = RateLimiter.of("telegram-rate-limiter",
                RateLimiterConfig.custom()
                        .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                        .limitForPeriod(20)
                        .build());
    }

    public void sendMessage(@PathVariable("token") String token, @RequestParam("chat_id") long chatId, @RequestParam("text") String message) {
        webClient.post().uri(String.format("/bot%s/sendMessage", token))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("chat_id", String.valueOf(chatId))
                        .with("text", message))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                .transformDeferred(RateLimiterOperator.of(rateLimiter))
                .block();
    }
```

The RateLimiter is used to ensure the number of requests does not exceed 20 a minute as specified in the Telegram API.

When the app is started, all requests are resolved normally as expected. But after some time has passed, all requests seem to get stuck. The amount of time needed for this to happen can vary from a few hours to a few days. It happens for all requests to different hosts and is easily noticeable when messages from the TelegramBot stops. Once the requests get stuck, they are stuck indefinitely and I have to restart the app to get it working again.

There are no exceptions in the log that seem to have caused this. Since I maintain a queue for my telegram messages, I can see the point in time when the requests stop when the number of messages in the queue steadily increases and when errors happen in the other processes that are waiting for the requests to resolve.

It does not seem like the requests are even sent out as the connect timeout and response timeout that I have set do not take effect.

I had previously also tried setting idle time to 0 but that did not solve the problem

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactorClientHttpConnector httpClient() {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.builder("connectionProvider").maxConnections(1000).maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(0)).build())
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newConnection()
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectTimeout)
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(responseTimeout));
        return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
    }
```

**Update:**

I enabled metrics and viewed it using micrometer when it got stuck. Interestingly, it shows that there is one connection for Telegram, but also shows no connections on idle, pending or active.

```
reactor_netty_connection_provider_idle_connections{id="-1268283746",name="connectionProvider",remote_address="api.telegram.org:443",} 0.0
reactor_netty_connection_provider_pending_connections{id="-1268283746",name="connectionProvider",remote_address="api.telegram.org:443",} 0.0
reactor_netty_connection_provider_active_connections{id="-1268283746",name="connectionProvider",remote_address="api.telegram.org:443",} 0.0
reactor_netty_connection_provider_total_connections{id="-1268283746",name="connectionProvider",remote_address="api.telegram.org:443",} 1.0
```

Could the issue be this missing connection?

**Update 2:**

I thought this might be related to this other issue: [Closing Reactor Netty connection on error status codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60833824/closing-reactor-netty-connection-on-error-status-codes)

So I updated my HttpClient to this:

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactorClientHttpConnector httpClient() {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.builder("connectionProvider").metrics(true).build())
                .doAfterResponseSuccess((r, c) -> c.dispose())
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectTimeout)
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(responseTimeout));
        return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
    }
```

But all that seemed to do is accelerate the occurrence of the problem. Just like before, the active, pending and idle connections do not add up to the total connections. The total is always greater than the other 3 metrics added together.

**Update 3:**
I did a thread dump when the issue happened. There were a total of 74 threads, so I don't think the app is running out of threads.

The dump for the Telegram thread:

```
"TelegramBot" #20 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=14.65ms elapsed=47154.24s tid=0x00007f6b28e73000 nid=0x1c waiting on condition  [0x00007f6aed6fb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.13/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fa865c80> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.13/LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(java.base@11.0.13/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(java.base@11.0.13/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1039)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(java.base@11.0.13/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1345)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(java.base@11.0.13/CountDownLatch.java:232)
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:87)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1707)
        at com.moon.arbitrage.cm.feign.TelegramClient.sendMessage(TelegramClient.java:59)
        at com.moon.arbitrage.cm.service.TelegramService.lambda$sendArbMessage$0(TelegramService.java:53)
        at com.moon.arbitrage.cm.service.TelegramService$$Lambda$1092/0x000000084070f840.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.moon.arbitrage.cm.service.TelegramService.task(TelegramService.java:82)
        at com.moon.arbitrage.cm.service.TelegramService$$Lambda$920/0x0000000840665040.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.13/Thread.java:829)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

The reactor worker threads:

```
"reactor-http-epoll-1" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=810.44ms elapsed=47157.07s tid=0x00007f6b281c4000 nid=0x17 runnable  [0x00007f6b0c46c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:177)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:286)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:351)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.13/Thread.java:829)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"reactor-http-epoll-2" #16 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1312.16ms elapsed=47157.07s tid=0x00007f6b281c5000 nid=0x18 waiting on condition  [0x00007f6b0c369000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.13/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fa865948> (a java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.13/LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(java.base@11.0.13/CompletableFuture.java:1796)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(java.base@11.0.13/ForkJoinPool.java:3128)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(java.base@11.0.13/CompletableFuture.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(java.base@11.0.13/CompletableFuture.java:1998)
        at com.moon.arbitrage.cm.service.OrderService.reconcileOrder(OrderService.java:103)
        at com.moon.arbitrage.cm.service.BotService$BotTask.lambda$task$1(BotService.java:383)
        at com.moon.arbitrage.cm.service.BotService$BotTask$$Lambda$1161/0x00000008400af440.accept(Unknown Source)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:171)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:702)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1372)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1235)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1284)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.13/Thread.java:829)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"reactor-http-epoll-3" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=171.84ms elapsed=47157.07s tid=0x00007f6b28beb000 nid=0x19 runnable  [0x00007f6b0c26a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:177)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:351)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.13/Thread.java:829)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"reactor-http-epoll-4" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=188.10ms elapsed=47157.07s tid=0x00007f6b28b7d800 nid=0x1a runnable  [0x00007f6b0c169000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:177)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:351)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.13/Thread.java:829)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

Seems like one of them is blocked with another task (that isn't even from the Telegram service) but that shouldn't be an issue since the other three worker threads are runnable right?

Comment: Are you able to replicate in your local workspace? Try pointing your spring app to a telegram api mock. If you are not able to  reproduce the error, it will be hard to help you

Comment: @JRichardsz I have tried to replicate it locally but to no avail, especially since this problem happens randomly after some time (could be days). Also, I used Telegram as an example, but this issue happens to all the hosts that I'm sending requests to. What's common across all the hosts is that the connections don't add up. I'm thinking and hoping that that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Try to generate a thread dump of your java process when the problem occurs and analyze the content. You might also be running out of threads. Which is the value of server.tomcat.threads.max. The default is 200.

Comment: Do you see "connection reset by peer" anywhere in logs? Asked because netty uses connection pooling by default and most of the api gateways closes idle connections after some time.

Comment: @Saxon while your suggestion was not the cause of my issue, it was your suggestion to generate a thread dump that led to me finding out the actual problem. Could you write an answer so I could award you the bounty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found and solved the problem. The issue was that I had a blocking task that was blocked on a reactor thread. I only noticed this thanks to the thread dump. The blocking task was waiting for an event, so it could take a long time to resolve. So eventually, when all four reactor threads are blocked, all requests would naturally be stuck with no threads to process them.

In short: don't block your reactor threads.

Comment: I know it's been a while.. but, do you have an example of the blocking task you're talking about? I'm facing a similar issue but I don't how we might be blocking the reactors threads.. It would very helpful

Answer (score 3):

I would propose to take a look in the RateLimiter direction.
Maybe it does not work as expected, depending on the number of requests your application does over time.
From the Javadoc for Ratelimiter:
"It is important to note that the number of permits requested never affects the throttling of the request itself ... but it affects the throttling of the next request. I.e., if an expensive task arrives at an idle RateLimiter, it will be granted immediately, but it is the next request that will experience extra throttling, thus paying for the cost of the expensive task."
Also helpful might be this discussion:
[github](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/1049) or [github](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/336)

I could imaginge there is some throttling adding up or other effect in the RateLimiter, i would try to play around with it and make sure this thing really works the way you want.
Alternatively, consider using Spring @Scheduled to read from your queue.
You might want to spice it up using embedded JMS for further goodies (message persistence etc).

Answer (score 1):

These problems are often related to thread exhaustion on spring-boot, and should be analyzed generating the thread dump at the time the block occurs with jstack:

```
jstack <java pid> > ThredDump.txt
```

The content of the generated file ThredDump.txt usually gives the info on blocked threads.

Comment: Sorry man, you posted it way too late. The bounty had already expired.